# Where does War of the planet of the apes (2017) stand in the chronology?

Tags: planet-of-the-apes, war-for-the-planet-of-the-apes

Where does *War of the Planet of the Apes* (2017) stand in the chronology of the movies, does it fall right after *Dawn of the Planet of the Apes* (2014) or is the follow up for *Dawn of the Planet of the Apes* (2014) a prequel to the original *Planet of the Apes* (1967) and *War* ends up after *Conquest of the Planet of the Apes* (1993)?

Comment: The Planet of the Apes was rebooted as a trilogy, with the first installment being Rise of the Planet of the Apes (2011), then came Dawn of the Planet of the Apes (2014), and finally we had War for the Planet of the Apes in 2017. This is a standalone trilogy, and only each of them are inter-related, in that order. You only need to watch them in the order of their release.